# How can I avoid my component remounting on redux update?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've noticed when an array in my redux state updates, the `connected` component gets remounted. In the logs after `dispatching` I see `~App` & `App` straight after. I'm under the impression that react/redux should update the component. I've looked through all the documentation and based on my understanding the react reconcile algorithm should not be behaving like this.

Sample code demonstrating the problem:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';


class AppComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(opts) {
    super(opts);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('App');
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('~App');
  }
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    console.log('shouldComponentUpdate');
  }
  render() {
    console.log('render');
    return (
      <span>hello</span>
    );
  }
};

const App = connect(
  (state, props) => {
    console.log('mapping state:', JSON.stringify(state));
    return {
      state
    };
  }
)(AppComponent);


const reducer = (state = [{id: 0, value: 'test0'}, {id: 1, value: 'test1'}], action) => {
  return state.map(o => {
    if (o.id === action.id) {
      return {
        ...o,
        value: action.value
      };
    }
    return o;
  });
};


const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);


setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('dispatching');
  store.dispatch({
    type: 'UPDATE',
    id: 1,
    value: 'test1 updated'
  });
}, 1000);
```

How can I avoid the `AppComponent` getting remounted? I don't have this issue if the redux state is not an array. Also, in other react/redux projects I haven't had this issue. Same npm package versions. I'm thinking I've made a stupid mistake somewhere here but am at a loss as to what I've done wrong. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put your code into a CodeSandbox, it appears to be running fine for me:

```
mapping state: 
[{"id":0,"value":"test0"},{"id":1,"value":"test1"}] 
render 
App cDM 
dispatching 
mapping state: 
[{"id":0,"value":"test0"},{"id":1,"value":"test1 updated"}] 
shouldComponentUpdate 
render
```

So, I think your code is actually okay.  Sandbox is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/k0k8rl8wzr):